# Files are not loading in Karma (Angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I am trying to test a simple controller in angularjs, 
but files for not getting loading into browser.
my files are as follows.

```
files: [ 'js/test.js','js/app.js','js/angular.min.js']
```

If I gave wrong file path also, Karma is not giving me any error/warning.

Example:

```
files: [ 'js/test_wrong_path.js','js/app_wrong_path.js','js/angular.min.js']
```

when i do karma start, only browser is getting launched. nothing is happening.

**app.js**

```
1.  angular.module('app', [])
1.  .controller('PasswordController', function PasswordController($scope) {
1.   $scope.password = '';
1.    $scope.grade = function() {
1.     var size = $scope.password.length;
1.     if (size > 8) {
1.       $scope.strength = 'strong';
3.     } else if (size > 3) {
3.       $scope.strength = 'medium';
3.     } else {
3.       $scope.strength = 'weak';
3.     }
3.   };
1. });
```

**test.js**

```
1. describe('PasswordController', function() {
1.   beforeEach(module('app'));

1.   var $controller;

1.   beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
    // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
1.     $controller = _$controller_;
1.   }));

1.   describe('$scope.grade', function() {
1.     it('sets the strength to "strong" if the password length is >8 chars', function() {
1.       var $scope = {};
1.       var controller = $controller('PasswordController', { $scope: $scope });
1.       $scope.password = 'longerthaneightchars';
1.       $scope.grade();
1.       expect($scope.strength).toEqual('strong');
1.    });
1.  });
1. });
```

Please help me to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have to generate a configuration file for Karma.

An initial config can be generated by using the *karma init* command. 
Read more about this here: http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html

Answer (score 0):

Files are not loading in required order.
1. Angular library files and dependent module JS files(js/angular.min.js) 
2. Application JS files(modules, controllers,directives,services,....) (js/app.js)
3. Jasmin files/ Unit Test cases files (js/test.js)